# Expo react native / always get same error, when trying to use icons

Tags: react-native, icons

I want to add some icons to my app but I keep getting the same error.

I tried to add icons to my app, but always get the same error.

First I tried with `@expo/vector-icons`  ([npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@expo/vector-icons/v/8.0.0?activeTab=readme)), installed successfully, but got this error:

> ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'isLoaded' of undefined

Here's the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

const App = () => {

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>This is a test</Text>
      <Ionicons name="md-checkmark-circle" size={32} color="green" />
    </View>
  )
}

export default App;
```

I also tried to import differently:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import FontAwesome from '@expo/vector-icons/FontAwesome';

const App = () => {

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>This is a test</Text>
      <FontAwesome name="facebook" size={32} color="green" />
    </View>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Next I wanted to try to use the library `react-native-vector-icons` ([npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-vector-icons)), also installed successfully, but got the same error:

> ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'isLoaded' of undefined

Here is the code: (used [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q2s6VTHl2kE) tutorial)

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import FontAwesomeIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';

const App = () => {

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>This is a test</Text>
      <FontAwesomeIcon name="star-o" size={50} />
    </View>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright. Problem solved.

Used wrong version for the library.
It can be easyl change, by running this following command:

> npx expo install --fix